# Visual Studio 2013 C# conditional assembly references?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

Currently i have a project which integrates to a 3rd party system using their .net API.
I am using VS 2013 to build the integration.
All is well...

Now the 3rd party company issues a new version of its software and .net API.
Their are no changes requried to my codebase however depending upon the target system i must reference either version 1 or version 2 of the 3rd parties API assemblies.

Currently i am doing a manual build by replacing the references for each version.
I would like to automate the build process but i can see no reference to being able to conditionally change the location of the API assemblies i reference, is it possible?

Comment: If you have to make no changes then it just doesn't matter what you build against.  Always build using the version 1 reference, deploy with a `<bindingRedirect>` in your app.exe.config file to use the version 2 DLL at runtime.

Comment: ah i forgot about bindingRedirect thanks!